# Not able to switch from main activity to listview

Tags: android, listactivity

I am not able to switch to the listactivity from my main acitivity , i created the listactivity by watching an video tutorial and followed the same steps but as soon as i click on the button to switch to the menu i am getting error "Unfortunately the program has stopped working "

```
Button button1; 
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

The Menu class is as follows :

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = {"First","Second","Third"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese=classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass=Class.forName("com.ashsoft.basiccprogram." + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent=new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Logcat :**

```
Log file : `01-13 13:53:03.481: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:03.481: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:03.481: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:04.511: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:04.521: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:05.602: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:05.602: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:05.681: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:05.771: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.001: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.071: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.071: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.181: I/Choreographer(1400): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-13 13:53:06.362: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.442: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.491: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.501: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.511: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.532: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.581: D/gralloc_goldfish(1400): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-13 13:53:06.702: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:06.851: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.741: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.782: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.801: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.801: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.872: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.911: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.931: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:16.951: W/Trace(1400): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-13 13:53:17.052: D/AndroidRuntime(1400): Shutting down VM
01-13 13:53:17.052: W/dalvikvm(1400): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ashsoft.basiccprogram/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 13:53:25.911: I/Process(1400): Sending signal. PID: 1400 SIG: 9
`
```

Manifest code :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.First"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FIRST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

The tutorial which i used did not use any xml file for the list.

Main problem is that the list is not showing up . Whenever i click on the button for menu from the main activity it stops working.

Comment: if you are working in eclipse, could you show us the logCat output?

Comment: i have added the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't registered that Menu class in your manifest file.

If it still doesn't work, post the logcat, so that there would be chances of having my answer edited.

**EDIT:**

First thing is your long process task must be sorrounded with asynctask.

For the time being let us leave that. Just try this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.ashsoft.basiccprogram.First"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.FIRST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".ListScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
```

**Your ListScreenActivity:**

```
public class ListScreenActivity extends ListActivity{
String classes[] = {"First","Second","Third"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListScreenActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));


               ListView listView = getListView();
           listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);




listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
               //show toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked on "+classes[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: how do i generate the log cat ?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't know the logcat? or If you don't know how to copy it. Just maximize the logcat window and take an image of it and post. Otherwise you click on the save button which would be availble on the upper right side of the logcat window and make it write to a file.

Comment: i have registered it in the manifest . i will also add the manifest with the log file in some minutes.

Comment: Have edited my answer. Change the name of the class menu to some other. Check it quickly and lemme know.One more thing is your logcat output that you posted is cut. Can you post a clear and full logcat output?

Comment: In the logcat, you can see the following: "01-13 13:53:17.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ashsoft.basiccprogram/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"; so there should be an activity listed as "com.ashsoft.basiccprogram/android.view.Menu" in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I have guessed it and warned the OP before my edit too. Even before I edited the question, the logcat was weird and I couldn't find the exact thing. But I have edited the question and checked it, by that time I couldn't edit my above comment.

Comment: i am getting an error on listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: `Description Resource Path Location Type
OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type ListScreenActivity.java /BasicCProgram/src/com/ashsoft/basiccprogram line 31 Java Problem`

and this one :
`Description Resource Path Location Type
The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){}) ListScreenActivity.java /BasicCProgram/src/com/ashsoft/basiccprogram line 31 Java Problem`

Comment: Paste your code by editing your question or paste it on websites like pastie and share that link over here.Unless that, I can't help you.